# Stay on question edit page after the actual posting

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Several times while posting a question (while clicking on the "Post your question" button) here on MSE I got weird behavior with the page. The browser asks me if I should leave the page or not to prevent losing some entered data instead of opening the page with recently published question:

> [image: Leave or stay]

In order to avoid losing my post I chose "Stay on Page" and pressed "Post your question" again. After that I saw the message that the post looks like a duplicate of an existing post:

> [image: duplicate]

That existing post is the question I just posted.

It seems that for some reason redirection to the posted question page occurs before the data is marked as saved.

My browser is Firefox 87.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else's experience of that version of Firefox, but it won't interact normally with a number of popular webpages, eg. Google play. It might just be in need of updating. I blame [Covid-associated worldwide software failures](https://www.designnews.com/design-software/2020-software-failures-linked-covid-19).